# How to rename a column using fix() function in R

Tags: r

I could see there are several ways to rename a column in R.

Can somebody please demonstrate how it can be done using fix() ?

Comment: If you use fix() on your desired data frame you will be able to edit the columns name by clicking it in the window that opens. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I actually wanted the syntax. But now I understand that the editing is done on a window that pops up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on the name in the display.  Depending on which platform you're using, you can either edit the name directly (R.app on MacOS), or will get an ugly menu allowing you to edit the name (RStudio on MacOS), or something else (some other platform).

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(z = 1:10, b = rnorm(10))
```

Oops, that should have been `a`, not `z`:

```
fix(df)
```

After I click on the `z`, I see this:

[image: screen shot]

and I can type whatever I like instead of `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt:
From `?fix`, we see that it simply takes an empty function for instance and allows you to edit it. Let's try to use it:

```
namer<-function(){

}
```

Now calling `fix(namer)` brings up an editable code `snippet` allowing you to change it as required.
I edited it as shown:

```
function(df,...){
    newnames<-c(...)#new
names(df)<-newnames#new

}
```

Trying it out:

```
 dummy_data<-data.frame(A=c("This is got from ?fix"),B=c("Really"))
   names(dummy_data)<-namer(dummy_data,"Works","Really")
   names(dummy_data)
[1] "Works"  "Really"
```

We have changed names(in a not so  great way):